# F# variable name

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Following are the few F# styles of variable naming. I am able to refer first two variable in my F# editor (through intelisense) but not the third variable. This is my first program using F# and just started crawling.

```
let simple="simple"
let ``let``=10
let ``son's birthday`` ="12/12/2012"
```

Comment: Intellisense is probably going haywire on weird identifiers, but you can still use the bound value just fine. I don't know the details of this behavior though... That being said, the *only* place I found custom identifiers like that to be usable so far was unit tests (naming both test modules and test functions). Outside of that, IMO, it looks like a prime candidate to cause a lot of grief...

Comment: I agree with you and it works when used without editor help.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek  They also come in handy when converting from other languages such as OCaml to F# and the OCaml name is not reserved but the F# one is reserved. You get around the problem using quotes.

Comment: @GuyCoder Oh, definitely, keyword conflict resolution is another example. Somehow it slipped my mind...

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug. Please report this at `fsbugs` at `Microsoft` dot com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reported this issue to Microsoft F# team and they responded with following note *"Thanks for the bug report!  I can reproduce the issue here, we will follow up on our side with a fix."*